# how to link category <option> tags

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I want to link categories to their own pages. so I mean when I click to 'Hotels' it should open the page which is Category/Hotels

[image]

this is the current code

```
<select name="category">
  <option value="">Any Category</option>
  <option value="clubs">Clubs</option></a>
  <option value="hotels">Hotels</option>
  <option value="pubbar">Pub&amp;Bar</option>
  <option value="restaurants">Restaurants</option>
</select>
```

lets say I want to link like that

```
  <option value="www.website.com/event_cat/clubs/> Clubs </option>
  <option value="www.website.com/event_cat/hotels/> Hotels </option>
.. and so on
```

but when I do, its directing to this page:

```
www.website.com/events/?time=&category=%2Fevent_cat%2Fclubs%2F&location=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSfiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/r6rddxd6/)

```
 <html>
    <body>
      <form name="blah_blah">
        <select name="ddmenu_name" id="ddmenu_name" style="width: 80% !important;">
          <option value="" selected>Select Site</option>
          <option value="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo!!!</option>
          <option value="http://www.gmail.com">Gmail</option>
          <option value="http://www.google.co.in">Google</option>
          <option value="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</option>
        </select>
        <input type="button" name="Submit" value="Go!" onClick="window.open(ddmenu_name.value,'newtab'+ddmenu_name.value)">
      </form>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, but how can I open link in same tab?
<button class="td-buttom" type="button" name="Submit" onClick="window.open(ddmenu_name.value,'newtab'+ddmenu_name.value)"> Go!</button>

Answer (score 1):

You just have to use full domain path with **http or https(if its a secure server)**

```
 <option value="http://www.website.com/event_cat/clubs/> Clubs </option>
 <option value="http://www.website.com/event_cat/hotels/> Hotels </option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the first option already selected, in the first option, keep the value empty and add the onchange, as per the code below:

```
<select onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
  <option value="">Any Category</option>
  <option value="www.website.com/event_cat/clubs/">Clubs</option>
  <option value="www.website.com/event_cat/hotels/">Hotels</option>
  <option value="pubbar">Pub&amp;Bar</option>
  <option value="restaurants">Restaurants</option>
</select>
```